Django Authentication Views: is there a way to disable some urls?
I'm working on a Django project and I'm using built in Authentication Views.
At the moment django provides me with the following url pattherns:
accounts/login/ [name='login']
accounts/logout/ [name='logout']
accounts/password_change/ [name='password_change']
accounts/password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
accounts/password_reset/ [name='password_reset']
accounts/password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done']
accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm']
accounts/reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete']

I use a very basic user system and I don't need all that functionalities. Is there a way to deactivate certain urls like 'password_reset' for example? Or to enable only a few of them?
[edit]
urls.py:
path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),


You haven't mentioned how your urls.py looks like. You should be able to add specific urls only in urls.py

I edited the question and added the urls.py file
